# multiple Buttons opens up same action but different ID container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple Buttons (12 at the moment), all have the same id with following letter.
each btn fire up a same function but different ID container.
here is the HTML:

```
<!----the btnS-->
<div id="projectA"></div>
<div id="projectB"></div>
<div id="projectC"></div>
<!--- The ContentS--->
<div class="content_projectA">this is content A!!!!
    <div id="closeA">
        <p class="text">close</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content_projectB">this is content B!!!!
    <div id="closeB">
        <p class="text">close</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content_projectC">this is content C!!!!
    <div id="closeC">
        <p class="text">close</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a code that working but it contains more than 500 lines... 
here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#projectA").on("click", function () {
        $(".content_projectA").slideDown();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 300
        }, 200);
    });

    $("#closeA").on("click", function () {
        $(".content_projectA").hide();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 200
        }, 400);
    });
});

//---- B -------//

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#projectB").on("click", function () {
        $(".content_projectB").slideDown();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 300
        }, 200);
    });

    $("#closeB").on("click", function () {
        $(".content_projectB").hide();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 200
        }, 400);
    });
});

//---- C -------//

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#projectC").on("click", function () {
        $(".content_projectC").slideDown();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 300
        }, 200);
    });

    $("#closeC").on("click", function () {
        $(".content_projectC").hide();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 200
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

I am looking for a way to short it up.

here is the code on fiddle- `http://jsfiddle.net/mirifarr/6j060L2k/`
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

please have a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6j060L2k/4/

```
<!----the btnS-->
<div class="project" id="projectA"></div>
<div class="project" id="projectB"></div>
<div class="project" id="projectC"></div>
<!--- The ContentS--->
<div class="content_projectA">this is content A!!!!
    <div  id="closeA">
    <p  id="A" class="close text">close</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content_projectB">this is content B!!!!
    <div id="closeB">
    <p id="B" class="close text">close</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content_projectC">this is content C!!!!
    <div id="closeC">
    <p id="C" class=" close text">close</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".project").on("click", function () {
    $(".content_"+$(this).attr('id')).slideDown();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: 300
    }, 200);
    });

    $(".close").on("click", function () {       
    //$(".content_projectA").hide();
    $(".content_project"+$(this).attr('id')).hide();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: 200
    }, 400);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following Jquery selector

[Selector On Starts With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

And Update your JS code like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//// Project
$("[id^='project']").click(function () {
    var char = $(this).attr('id').substring(7);

    $(".content_project" + char).slideDown();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: 300
    }, 200);
});

///// Close Div
$("[id^='close']").click(function () {
    var char = $(this).attr('id').substring(5);

    $(".content_project" + char).hide();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: 200
    }, 400);
});

});
```

[Check Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6j060L2k/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery *starts with* selector `^`. Retrieve the last character of the clicked div and use to scroll to target div.

```
$("[id^=project]").on("click", function () {
   var id = this.id,
       letter = id.substr(id.length - 1);
});
```

Use the `letter` to target div with class `content_project`. Do the same for `close` button/div.

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/00przxqn/show/) looks better than code snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id^=project]").on("click", function () {
        var id = this.id,
            letter = id.substr(id.length - 1);
        $(".content_project" + letter).slideDown();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 300
        }, 200);
    });

    $("[id^=close]").on("click", function () {
        var id = this.id,
            letter = id.substr(id.length - 1);
        $(".content_project" + letter).hide();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 200
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

```css
#projectA {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #0f36ca;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#projectB {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #0ff5ca;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#projectC {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #6f36ca;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.content_projectA {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0f36ca;
    display: none;
}
.content_projectB {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0ff5ca;
    display: none;
}
.content_projectC {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #6f36ca;
    display: none;
}
.text {
    color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
}
#closeA {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#closeB {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#closeC {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!----the btnS-->
<div id="projectA"></div>
<div id="projectB"></div>
<div id="projectC"></div>
<!--- The ContentS--->
<div class="content_projectA">this is content A!!!!
    <div id="closeA">
        <p class="text">close</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content_projectB">this is content B!!!!
    <div id="closeB">
        <p class="text">close</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content_projectC">this is content C!!!!
    <div id="closeC">
        <p class="text">close</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @miri if you like it, accept it :) and you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't change the CSS, so i won't post it again.

**js:**

```
    function openContents(classChar) {

    //this don't need to be inside an onclick event because this event is already triggered when accessing this function
    $(".content_project"+classChar).slideDown();
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: 300
    }, 200); 

    //this one continues to bind the event to the close div
    $("#close"+classChar).on("click", function () {
        $(".content_project"+classChar).hide();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 200
        }, 400);
    });
}

//on document ready, execute init()
function init() {

    /*
     * What I did here was bind a click event to all three divs, using a class to identify them, instead of picking one by one.
     * Then store id value of clicked div in a variable and sending the last char as parameter to openContents function.
     */
    $(".projects").on("click",function() {
        var idValue = $(this).attr('id');
        openContents(idValue.substr(idValue.length-1));
    });

}

$(document).ready(init);
```

**html (just added classes):**

```
<!----the btnS-->
<div id="projectA" class="projects"></div>
<div id="projectB" class="projects"></div>
<div id="projectC" class="projects"></div>
<!--- The ContentS--->
<div class="content_projectA">this is content A!!!!
    <div id="closeA">
        <p class="text">close</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content_projectB">this is content B!!!!
    <div id="closeB">
        <p class="text">close</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content_projectC">this is content C!!!!
    <div id="closeC">
        <p class="text">close</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6j060L2k/9/